# python ply syntax error,can't parse d[0-9]+

Tags: python, ply

I'm trying to parse this list:
`d0,d1,d2,d3,....d456,d457....`

To parse this in python-ply, I wrote this as expression :

```
t_DID                   =   r'[d][0-9]+'
t_DID                   =   r'd[0-9]+'
t_DID                   =   r'\d[0-9]+'
```

But, it provides me error.

When, I enter 1, it gives me - *DEBUG:root:Syntax error at '1'*

And when I enter d, it gives me - *DEBUG:root:Syntax error at 'd'*

What would be the correct token, for this pattern?

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Could you add the code that rise the error and your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those patterns match either `d` or `1`.

- `r'[d][0-9]+'` and `r'd[0-9]+'` match a `d` followed by at least one digit. So they will match `d1` or `d234`, but they won't match `d` because it is not followed by a digit, and they will not match `1` because it doesn't start with `d`
- `r'\d[0-9]+'` matches a digit (`\d`) followed by at least one digit more. So it won't match any string starting with `d`, and it won't match `1` because it requires at least two digits. But it will match `12`, `274` and `29847502948375029384750293485702938750493875`.

You can read about Python regular expressions in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) (The `\` escape codes, including `\d`, are [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)).

It's easy to build an interactive tool which lets you experiment with Python regular expressions. Here's a *very* simple example, which could be improved a lot:

```py
$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> import readline
>>> def try_regex(regex):
...   r = re.compile(regex)
...   try:
...     while True:
...       match = r.match(input('--> '))
...       if match:
...         print(f"Matched {match.end()} characters: {match[0]}")
...       else:
...         print("No match")
...   except EOFError:
...     pass
... 
>>> try_regex(r'd[0-9]+')
--> d1
Matched 2 characters: d1
--> d123
Matched 4 characters: d123
--> 1
No match
--> d
No match
--> d123 abc
Matched 4 characters: d123
--> d123abc
Matched 4 characters: d123
```